# Azure devops Pipelines: Cannot find Docker Image when Pushing to Azure Registry, 'tag ***/appname'

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

We build our docker image with a custom .sh file. Then we would like to push it to our azure registry. We have the following step in our azure pipeline:

```
    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'someazureregistry'
        repository: 'appname'
        command: 'push'
        tags: 'latest'
```

The build is successfull, and as can be seen below it is registered in docker as `appname:latest` , however for some reason azure does not find it, and asks for an image with the tag `***/appname`.

```
/usr/bin/docker images
/usr/bin/docker push ***/appname:latest
REPOSITORY       TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED                  SIZE
appname         latest      f1e11b4fc19c   Less than a second ago   680MB
ubuntu           20.04       a0ce5a295b63   7 days ago               72.8MB
...
The push refers to repository [***/appname]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: ***/appname
##[error]An image does not exist locally with the tag: ***/appname
```

We have tried different combinations of tags. What is azure expecting here?

Comment: when you build it you need to build it with the `containerRegistry` as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are building the Docker image separately. Please note that **the container image needs to be tag locally for the private container registry before it can be pushed**. As Shayki Abramczyk mentioned you need to build the image with `containerRegistry`.

To resolve this issue you must Tag the image using the "[docker tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/)" command with the specific private container registry.

For example:

```
docker tag image youoregistryhost:port/xxx/image-name:latest
```

Besides, you can build and push the Docker image together in Azure DevOps pipeline. The following YAML file for your reference:

```
variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'testacr'
  imageRepository: 'appname'
  containerRegistry: 'xxx.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/app/Dockerfile'
  tag: 'latest'
  system.debug : true
  
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
   
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

Of course you can also `build` and `push` the image separately in Azure DevOps pipeline like this:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build an image for container registry
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: '$(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)'
        repository: '$(imageRepository)'
        command: 'build'
        Dockerfile: '$(dockerfilePath)'
        tags: 'latest'
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: '$(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)'
        repository: '$(imageRepository)'
        command: 'push'
        tags: 'latest'
```

Comment: Tagging it in this format did the job, thank you!